# How to get array from non-array field for INSERT command?

Tags: arrays, postgresql

I'm trying to use a `SELECT` statement together with a `INSERT INTO` command. Everything would work fine, if there wasn't a small problem: some fields of the table are defined as `real[]` but my input is `numeric`. Thus, the question:

**Is there a function in PostgreSQL to create out of the single numeric input an array of type real (with just one element)?**

My setting looks like this:

```
tempLogTable(..., logValue NUMERIC, ...)
finalLogTable(..., logValues REAL[], ...)
```

The idea is to insert the tuples from the `tempLogTable` to the `finalLogTable` using `INSERT INTO ... SELECT ...`. Unfortunately, because of various reasons the data types are given and I would not like to change these for the moment (not to break anything).

I'm using PostgreSQL 9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT ARRAY[thenumeric::real] FROM the_table;
```

or

```
SELECT ARRAY[thenumeric]::real[] FROM the_table;
```

They're not really any different for a one-element array.

`real` has limits that `numeric` doesn't. In particular, comparing `real` values for equality doesn't work reliably; you should instead compare for two numerics being different by smaller than a small (somewhat task-specific) amount. It also can't represent values as big or small as numeric can. See [the floating point guide](http://floating-point-gui.de/errors/comparison/) among other info on comparing floats. This will be much harder to do right when they're wrapped in arrays.

For the purpose you describe, where it sounds like you are just collecting stats or historical data, that isn't going to be a problem. It usually only turns out to be an issue where people try to write:

```
WHERE some_real = some_other_real
```

which will result in surprising and unexpected behaviour.

You should be fine with an `INSERT INTO ... SELECT` as described.

Comment: Ah! That's a nice solution! Thanks also for the hint for comparing `real`!

Comment: I'm really sorry about not being precise! I updated my question with more information!

Comment: Thanks for the very clarifying answer! It works very good! Thanks!